# CSS: insert a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script which is looking for the class "image". It is working and I tried the script on a blank page. The only code who is written on this page is:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

But now I want to get this script working in a plugin so the only way to insert the class image in the plugin is via CSS...

How can I say in CSS something like:

```
background-image: <div class="image"></div>
```

Greetings and Thank you!

Comment: CSS cannot add or remove classes from elements. Only JavaScript is able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, you can assign by

```
background:url(./images.png)
```

or can use javascipts to pass/update the value.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting classes via CSS is not possible. CSS is only meant to control  the presentation of html.